# the time of execution increases from -o0 to -os ..so is the time referring to compilation time or execution time..?

Tags: c

As we  know that the time increases from -0o to -0s in gcc.
does the time referring to compiling time or execution time or both ?
as there is  change in binary from -o0 to -os, then the way instructions executes will  also differ, so the time of execution will also alter is this correct..?

Answer (score 1):

in general as you increase the optimization levels, you're asking the compiler to work harder, so compilation time is longer.  The execution time should be shorter, because that's the entire purpose of optimizing your code.

Naturally, your binary will be different based on how the compiler optimizes the code.

Optimizations may include:

- inlining code
- removing temporary variables
- simplifying expressions
- and much more

each of these can affect the code that is generated.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question it is about why size optimized code is slower than speed optimized code or unoptimized code.

Many optimization techniques like inlining functions or unrolling loops gain speed by increasing code size.

When optimizing with -os all optimizations of -02 are applied that do not increase code size.
More details you find here:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html